# PHP ARRAY ERROR al intentar guardar la informacion de una consulta en un array solo me muestra el último dato

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Tengo una función llamada invoice, que consulta registros en bd en la tabla historial_donaciones.

Consulta:

```
public function invoices(int $id_usuario)
{
    $this->userId = $id_usuario;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM historial_donaciones INNER JOIN users on historial_donaciones.donador = users.usuario_id OR historial_donaciones.beneficiario = users.usuario_id WHERE users.usuario_id = $this->userId" ;
    $request = $this->select_All($sql);}
```

La consulta funciona a la perfección y me trae los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [donacion_id] => 3
            [donador] => 42
            [beneficiario] => 1
            [dinero] => 10000
            [ciudad] => Barrancabermeja
            [fecha] => 2023-04-02 06:54:07
            [status] => 0
            [usuario_id] => 1
            [codigo_id] => asdqr235we5
            [rol_id] => 1
            [usuario] => Chuka
            [contrasena] => 8b37c6ce2760890d810fc862cffaecd4020d3f3755f9b5189d6cd5f7c8833b27
            [sponsor] => 1
            [email] => xchukaflete@gmail.com
            [celular] => 3089006754
            [paquete_id] => 1
            [matriz] => activo
            [fecha_registro] => 2023-03-30 00:00:00
            [token] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [donacion_id] => 4
            [donador] => 1
            [beneficiario] => 44
            [dinero] => 10000
            [ciudad] => Barrancabermeja
            [fecha] => 2023-04-02 06:54:07
            [status] => 0
            [usuario_id] => 1
            [codigo_id] => asdqr235we5
            [rol_id] => 1
            [usuario] => Chuka
            [contrasena] => 8b37c6ce2760890d810fc862cffaecd4020d3f3755f9b5189d6cd5f7c8833b27
            [sponsor] => 1
            [email] => xchukaflete@gmail.com
            [celular] => 3089006754
            [paquete_id] => 1
            [matriz] => activo
            [fecha_registro] => 2023-03-30 00:00:00
            [token] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [donacion_id] => 5
            [donador] => 1
            [beneficiario] => 42
            [dinero] => 10000
            [ciudad] => Barrancabermeja
            [fecha] => 2023-04-02 06:54:57
            [status] => 0
            [usuario_id] => 1
            [codigo_id] => asdqr235we5
            [rol_id] => 1
            [usuario] => Chuka
            [contrasena] => 8b37c6ce2760890d810fc862cffaecd4020d3f3755f9b5189d6cd5f7c8833b27
            [sponsor] => 1
            [email] => xchukaflete@gmail.com
            [celular] => 3089006754
            [paquete_id] => 1
            [matriz] => activo
            [fecha_registro] => 2023-03-30 00:00:00
            [token] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [donacion_id] => 12
            [donador] => 44
            [beneficiario] => 1
            [dinero] => 10000
            [ciudad] => Barrancabermeja
            [fecha] => 2023-04-04 00:52:26
            [status] => 0
            [usuario_id] => 1
            [codigo_id] => asdqr235we5
            [rol_id] => 1
            [usuario] => Chuka
            [contrasena] => 8b37c6ce2760890d810fc862cffaecd4020d3f3755f9b5189d6cd5f7c8833b27
            [sponsor] => 1
            [email] => xchukaflete@gmail.com
            [celular] => 3089006754
            [paquete_id] => 1
            [matriz] => activo
            [fecha_registro] => 2023-03-30 00:00:00
            [token] => 
        )

)
```

en el ejemplo, hice la consulta para el  usuario_id = 1, el problema es que el id = 1, en el registro [0] es beneficiario y en otros como en el registro [1] es donante como pueden ver.

entonces lo que intento es separar la consulta en un array de la siguiente manera:

```
$array = array(
   'soy_beneficiario' => array(
         'los registros en los que el id=1 es beneficiario'
    ),
   'soy_donador' =>  array(
         'los registros en los que el id=1 es donador'
     )
);
```

Adicional quiero ejecutar otra consulta, si el id=1 es donador entonces que me consulte los datos de la persona que es beneficiaria y viceversa. para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($request); $i++) { 
            if ($request[$i]['beneficiario'] == $this->userId) {
                $beneficiario = $request[$i];
                $dinero = formatMoney($beneficiario['dinero']);
                $ciudad = $beneficiario['ciudad'];
                $fecha = $beneficiario['fecha'];
                $status = $beneficiario['status'];
                $id_donacion = $beneficiario['donacion_id'];
                $donador = $beneficiario['donador'];
                $datosDonador = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario_id = $donador" ;
                $request2 = $this->select_All($datosDonador);
                

                $nombreDonador = $request2[0]['usuario'];
                $correoDonador = $request2[0]['email'];
                $celularDonador = $request2[0]['celular'];

                $datosDonacion = array(
                    'tipo' => 'beneficiario',
                    'id_donacion' => $id_donacion,
                    'valor' => $dinero,
                    'ciudad' => $ciudad,
                    'fecha' => $fecha,
                    'status' => $status,
                    'usuario' => $nombreDonador,
                    'correo' => $correoDonador,
                    'celular' => $celularDonador
                );

                

            }elseif ($request[$i]['donador'] == $this->userId) {
                $donador = $request[$i];
                $id_beneficiario = $donador['beneficiario'];
                $id_donacion = $donador['donacion_id'];
                $dinero = formatMoney($donador['dinero']);
                $ciudad = $donador['ciudad'];
                $fecha = $donador['fecha'];
                $status = $donador['status'];
                
                $datosBeneficiado = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario_id = $id_beneficiario" ;
                $request3 = $this->select_All($datosBeneficiado);
                $nombreDonador = $request3[0]['usuario'];
                $correoDonador = $request3[0]['email'];
                $celularDonador = $request3[0]['celular'];
                $datosDonacion = array(
                    'tipo' => 'donador',
                    'id_donacion' => $id_donacion,
                    'valor' => $dinero,
                    'ciudad' => $ciudad,
                    'fecha' => $fecha,
                    'status' => $status,
                    'usuario' => $nombreDonador,
                    'correo' => $correoDonador,
                    'celular' => $celularDonador
                );
            }
            return $datosDonacion ;
        }
```

el error está en que solo me agrega un solo registro en la variable $datosDonacion, lo que creo es que solo crea el primer registro es decir:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [donacion_id] => 3
            [donador] => 42
            [beneficiario] => 1
            [dinero] => 10000
            [ciudad] => Barrancabermeja
            [fecha] => 2023-04-02 06:54:07
            [status] => 0
            [usuario_id] => 1
            [codigo_id] => asdqr235we5
            [rol_id] => 1
            [usuario] => Chuka
            [contrasena] => 8b37c6ce2760890d810fc862cffaecd4020d3f3755f9b5189d6cd5f7c8833b27
            [sponsor] => 1
            [email] => xchukaflete@gmail.com
            [celular] => 3089006754
            [paquete_id] => 1
            [matriz] => activo
            [fecha_registro] => 2023-03-30 00:00:00
            [token] => 
        )
```

alguien sabe que pasa? por que por mas que recorro el resultado de la consulta inicial y lo meto en una variable solo me agrega 1 resultado, agradezco mucho si alguien me ayuda

Comment: No entendí del todo lo que quieres obtener, pero, revisando tu código, pinta muy mal lo que estás haciendo. Por lo general no es buena idea lanzar consultas dentro de bucles. Si ese bucle tiene mil iteracciones, estarás lanzando 1000 consultas. Considera organizar los datos ya en la consulta. Puede que necesites manejar una tabla donde indiques las donaciones.

Comment: wow bro, muchas gracias no habia pensado en eso tienes mucha razón muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes declarar el array antes del bucle

```php
$datosDonacion = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($request); $i++) { 
///resto del codigo
    array_push($datosDonacion , array(
       'tipo' => 'beneficiario',
       'id_donacion' => $id_donacion,
       'valor' => $dinero,
       'ciudad' => $ciudad,
       'fecha' => $fecha,
       'status' => $status,
       'usuario' => $nombreDonador,
       'correo' => $correoDonador,
       'celular' => $celularDonador
       ));
}
```

Saludos, espero te sirva

Comment: Bro muchas gracias, funciona ahora si, pero como dicen en el primer comentario creo que estaba estructurando muy mal el code, lo replatié, muchas gracias por tomar un poco te tu valioso tiempo para responderme lo valoro mucho